# Como detectar o fim da leitura de um arquivo em um loop com while em C++

Tags: c++, arquivo, struct, get

No meu código, tem a struct:

```
struct material {
    int idmaterial;
    double rho;
    double precokg;
};
```

E a função de leitura de um vetor de dados do tipo "material", a partir de um arquivo:

```
std::vector<material> le_material(std::string s)
{
    std::ifstream dados(s);
    dados.exceptions(std::ios::failbit |
            std::ios::badbit);

    std::vector<material> infomateriais;
    material mat_lido;
    bool fim;
    fim = dados.eof();

    while (fim == false) {
        dados >> mat_lido.idmaterial;
        dados >> mat_lido.rho;
        dados >> mat_lido.precokg;
        infomateriais.push_back(mat_lido);
        fim = dados.eof();
    }

    return infomateriais;
}
```

Sendo que o arquivo a ser lido contém os seguintes dados:

```
1   1.02    82.76   
2   2.81    29.45   
3   1.46    14.41   
4   1.15    31.54   
5   1.04    71.10   
6   1.11    87.05   
7   2.84    13.81   
8   1.56    27.55   
9   2.63    71.30   
10  0.87    25.59   
11  2.99    24.83
```

Creio que a leitura dos dados está ok. Entretanto, o programa dá erro na execução quando atinge o final do arquivo:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]'   what():  basic_ios::clear:
>   iostream error Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)

De começo, descobri que é porque a função *eof()* na verdade só retorna *true* quando é feita uma tentativa de leitura que atinge o final do arquivo, sendo assim, o programa ainda tentaria fazer a leitura.

Algumas dúvidas:

- Há alguma maneira de se utilizar o *eof()* sem se tentar fazer uma
  leitura e dar erro na execução do programa?
- Tentei utilizar na condição do *while* o operador >> , verificando se
  havia sucesso na leitura e continuou dando erro, pois, pelo o que
  pesquisei, ele tentaria ler o espaço em branco final e não detectaria
  que é o fim do arquivo. Então, seria melhor usar o *get()*? Como
  poderia ser feito esse uso?

Comment: Provavelmente, a leitura está parando nos espaços. Tente fazer a leitura em um só comando: `dados >> mat_lido.idmaterial >> mat_lido.rho >> mat_lido.precokg;`

Comment: Continua dando o mesmoerro. Ele faz a leitura 11 vezes (como era esperado), mas chegando no final dá o erro que coloquei na minha pergunta.
Como eu detecto o fim do arquivo se eu usar o comando que você me sugeriu?

Comment: O arquivo texto termina exatamente após o `3` do número `24.83`? Se houver, por exemplo, um *new line* (ENTER) ou qualquer outro caracter depois do `3`, ele dará erro

Comment: Não. Há uma espécie de tabulamento ou espaçamento logo após o número. Só que eu tenho que ler esse arquivo assim mesmo, não há nenhum jeito de fazer isso se ele não termina no último número?

Comment: Há vários jeitos :) Mas se não tiver esse caracter é bem mais fácil. Uma sugestão seria mudar a leitura para texto com [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) e separar os números, por exemplo, com *stoi* e *stod*