# Por que ocorre um erro chegando no fim de um arquivo que termina com espaços em branco em um loop com while, utilizando o operador de leitura >>?

Tags: c++, arquivo, while

Eu quero executar uma função de leitura de um vetor "material" (eu criei este tipo com "struct"). A leitura será executada a partir de um arquivo.

```
std::vector<material> material_read(std::string s)
{
    std::ifstream data(s);
    dados.exceptions(std::ios::failbit |
            std::ios::badbit);

    std::vector<material> infomaterials;
    material mat_read;

    while (data >> mat_read.idmaterial) {
        data >> mat_read.idmaterial;
        data >> mat_read.rho;
        data >> mat_read.pricekg;
        infomaterials.push_back(mat_read);
    }

    return infomaterials;
}
```

O arquivo que devo ler (e não posso fazer alterações) é o seguinte, com espaços após todas as linhas:

```
1   1.02    82.76   
2   2.81    29.45   
3   1.46    14.41   
4   1.15    31.54   
5   1.04    71.10   
6   1.11    87.05   
7   2.84    13.81   
8   1.56    27.55   
9   2.63    71.30   
10  0.87    25.59   
11  2.99    24.83
```

Acho que ler cada número em cada linha está indo bem.
No entanto, há um erro na execução, quando atinge o final do arquivo:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]'   what():  basic_ios::clear:
>   iostream error Abortado (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Eu testei imprimindo algo na tela antes e depois de cada operação de leitura. Realmente faz todas as 33 leituras que eu esperava. Mas depois de ler o 33º valor, ele nem entra no loop while novamente e, em seguida, mostra o erro.

É possível que, como os data >> mat_read.idmaterial falha, me dê a mensagem de erro?
Isso está acontecendo porque o arquivo termina com espaços?

Comment: Você está lendo duas vezes o dado `mat_read.idmaterial` e, ao setar o `exceptions` a variável `dados` não existe. Na sua [outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298736/como-detectar-o-fim-da-leitura-de-um-arquivo-em-um-loop-com-while-em-c) pergunta, eu já havia sugerido uma outra forma de leitura que deve funcionar